# Set Status Bar Color based on webpage meta color ios

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm using WKWebView to load a webapp. The webapp has a different meta color value on each page. The meta color is available in a  tag of the webpage.

Now, I was wondering if it possible (in any way), to load the HTML meta color value and set it as status bar color?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: hi! did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: @WitekBobrowski, sorry I haven't opened up SO in few days. But the solution you provided wouldn't work for me as it is messing up with the status bar texts + icons.

Comment: what do you mean is it messing up? I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achive then. Could you give some more details?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the color of the status bar contents like text, icons. You can only switch between dark and light styles of the status bar.

```swift
// in your view controller
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent // or .darkContent or .default
}
```

You will need to call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` when you want to refresh status bar style.

It is possible to change the background color of the view behind the status bar. Simply make sure that the view is not constrained to the safe area layout guide, but to the [topAnchor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622613-topanchor) of the view controller that contains the web view.